# Goku super saiyan 4 vs super saiyan god

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-z, dragonball-gt, dragonball-super

Now with the new Dragon Ball series, there is a new Goku transformation, Super Saiyan God, in which he becames stronger than when he is in Super Saiyan 3. But that also happens when he transforms in Super Saiyan 4 in the GT series.

So, does anyone knows which one of Goku transformations is the strongest?

Goku Super Saiyan 4 or Goku Super Saiyan God?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In the current series Super Saiyan God is the strongest form**

Technically at the point of Super Saiyan God, Super Saiyan 4 no longer exists in the Dragonball canon.

Dragonball GT was removed from the canon and replaced with the Battle of the Gods movie and then of course the series Dragonball Super. We've also never had a power multiplier stated for SSJ4 the multipliers floating around are fan based where you take the accumulated multiplier for SS 1-3 (base x50x2x4 = base x400) and then multiply that by Oozaru's 10x mutliplier (base x4,000). AFAIK there is not official number for SSJG multiplier out yet either.

However I've done some research, and because of the crazy power levels Toei Animation decided to go with in GT in seems to be that SSJ4 (at the end of GT) would be stronger than the **current** SSJG transformation.

Although you should know that SSJ4 does not exist as of Drangonball Super. SSJG seems to be Toriyamas ultimate Super Saiyan level, as such it will only grow in power.

Comment: What about SSGSS? http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_God_Super_Saiyan

Answer (score 0):

### The truth is there is no official reference known about SSG power levels yet.

Apart from that, I think SSJ4 is stronger than SSG, even knowing SSJ4 and all the GT content doesn't belong to the Dragon Ball story anymore.
Now, we've got to think about the new developments on *Dragon Ball Super*, where both Goku and Vegeta reached the **SSGSS** form, which certainly surpasses the SSJ4.
Having that in consideration, we can go even further and think about the latest achievement of Goku, reaching the ***SSGSS Kaio-Ken x10*** form, that by all means, is the ultimate Saiyan form until now.
We don't know if there will be any stronger variation but, for now, we should have in consideration this form that Goku accomplished.

#### Conclusion: SSGSS Kaio-Ken x10 is clearly stronger than SSJ4.

Answer (score 0):

In the video game: Extreme Butoden, syn shenrons full power can also be greatly empowered by acquiring enough negative energy from the Z Fighters battling various villains, with this power Omega Shenron is able to create the Ultimate Minus Energy Power Ball - an attack capable of destroying the universe, however even with this power up, Omega Shenron is defeated by Super Saiyan God Goku. So ssj4 wasn't even able to beat omega shenron but ssjg could beat a more powerful omega shenron.

Answer (score -1):

***Super Saiyan 4(SSJ4) vs Super Saiyan God(SSG)***

Just Theory since there is no actual power level is declared.

**Theory**  :- The Creation of SSJ4 and SSG
SSJ4 is the result of Goku's own control over the power when he transformed into APE and started destroying everything until PAN interrupted him and he was able to control it

SSG is result of 5 Saiyans(**Gohan,Vegeta,Goten,Trunk,and Videls** baby which was still not born yet but was inside belly) giving their power to 6th Saiyan

**So, the Chances of Goku is SSG is Maybe more powerful then SSJ4**